# Find the radius of convergence and interval of convergence for the given series $\sum_{n}^{\infty}{n^n(x+3)^n}/(n^{100}+100n+29)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

Find the radius of convergence and interval of convergence for the given series
$$\sum_{n}^{\infty}{n^n(x+3)^n}/(n^{100}+100n+29)$$
I'm trying to use the ratio test to find the radius of convergence $R$ and the interval of convergence $I$, but I'm stuck on how to set up the problem, i.e. should $n^n$ turn into $n^{n+1}$ or $(n+1)^{n+1}$ (I believe its the latter). And if so then what terms cancel? And if I ends up being more than one number what endpoints converge/diverge?

Answer (score 1):

By using the ratio test and since we have $$\lim_{n\to \infty}{(n+1)^{n+1}\over n^{n}}{=
\lim_{n\to \infty}{(n+1)^{n}\cdot (n+1)\over n^{n}}
\\=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left({1+{1\over n}}\right)^n(n+1)
\\=\lim_{n\to \infty}e(n+1)
\\=\infty
}$$then the radius of convergence is $0$.